# How to validate form on submit?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate form onSubmit in my React Application. I would like to add features like ,when one of the conditions returns false,for example red outline will be added to that input ,and inside that input will be placeholder with that Error.

This is one of the components which is rendered in main file. This components is called by click on set alarm button. This is not that important ,but what is ,I'm sending getInfo() function from main component to this component as a prop. I need to call this function when validation returns true

Form consists of 3 input fields and one button ,but I don't need to check the first one.

Since my application is Alarm clock ,and this form pops up when you click Set alarm button , I need to check if

First input is not empty and if it's value is not over 24 (in this input you set hours for alarm)
Second input is not empty and if it's value is not over 60 (in this input you set minutes for alarm)
My idea was to create States for these values and create functions which are supposed to update states. Functions are called onChange that specific input.

```
const [validate,setValidate] = useState({
    message:'',
    hours:'',
    minutes:''
}) 

function updateHours(e){
    let value = e.target.value
    setValidate(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
       hours:value
    }))
}

function updateMinutes(e){
    let value = e.target.value;
    setValidate(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        minutes:value
    }))
}
```

To this point everything works fine. Then I've tried to create new function which will be validating these values and should return the result. This function will be called onSubmit ,and if returns true ,it means everything is okay and form will be send.

```
let getInfo = props.getInfo;

function validateForm(){
if(validate.hours > 24){
    alert('enter correct hours !')
    return false;
}

if(validate.minutes > 60){
    alert('enter correct minutes !')
    return false;
}

return getInfo;
}
```

I've tried to Google it how to do this onSubmit and all I can find was this approach ,which did not work. It behaves like no function is called.

```
<form onSubmit="return validateForm">
 <FontAwesomeIcon 
    icon={faTimesCircle} 
    className="closeIcon"
    onClick={() => setAlarm(false)} />

 <h3>Please set your alarm</h3>

 <label htmlFor="text">Message</label>
 <input type="text" id="text" autoComplete="off" autoFocus="on" />

 <div className="flex">
   <div className="inputNumber">
      <label htmlFor="hours">Hour</label>
      <input type="number" id="hours" name="hours" onChange={updateHours} />
   </div>
                            
   <div className="inputNumber">
      <label htmlFor="minutes">Minute</label>
      <input type="number" id="minutes" name="minutes" onChange={updateMinutes} />
   </div>
</div>
<button onClick={()=>setAlarm(false)}>SET ALARM</button>
```

Has anyone encountered this kind of problem or can you give me advice what to do with it? Also I'm open-minded to some better approach for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's look a bit look but have tried something like this?
Instead of returning the function, just call it.

```
function validateForm(){
    if(validate.hours > 24 || validate.minutes > 60) {
        if(validate.hours > 24) alert('enter correct hours !')

        if(validate.minutes > 60) alert('enter correct minutes !')
    }
    else getInfo();
}
```

If it's not helped you, can you provide us a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to understand better :) (you can use [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/))

Comment: I’ll try that today :) but i think I’ve already tried it a it doesn’n work . I’ll let you know here in comment section and provide you codesandbox :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find that I almost never rely on the default form submission in react, and will usually call some API, instead. I expect this is what you will be doing, so I will recommend a solution with that in mind.

First, the validation function. It should prevent the default form submission, check your form values and set error states. If everything is in order, then it should submit the action.

```js
function validateForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //stop the default browser behavior
  if(validate.hours > 24){
    alert('enter correct hours !')
    return;
  }

  if(validate.minutes > 60){
    alert('enter correct minutes !')
    return;
  }

  performMyApiCall();
}
```

Second, the html. Remember, onSubmit is a React property on a React component. You need to give it a function. The function will take a parameter `e`, which is the event detail.

```
<form onSubmit={validateForm}>
  //snip
</form>
```

This should help you to manually set your validation. That said, unless I'm doing something out of the ordinary, I use an existing package to do form validation. I use material-ui as a frontend library, and so often turn to [react-material-ui-form-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-form-validator).